# How to correct download multiple images(thumbnails for videos)

Tags: java, android, download

I write client for kaltura media platform.
I have an activity "Video". In this activity I must display list of video with thumbnails
First of all, I download list of videos using kaltura api, and this works fine. Every video entry have a field thumbnailUrl, which point out to thumbnail for video.
When I download this thumbnails for videos, it's(thumbnails) downloads in incorrect order, some thumbnails not downloaded, some thumbnails repeated for other video, and some not downloaded.
This is code of callback if downloadind videos:

```
private void handleFetchvideoListTask(List<VideoObject> videoObjects){
        LinearLayout videoListProgressBarContainer = (LinearLayout)mActivity.findViewById(R.id.videoListProgressBarContainer);
        LinearLayout videoListViewContainer = (LinearLayout)mActivity.findViewById(R.id.videoListViewContainer);

        videoListProgressBarContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        videoListViewContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        ListView listView = (ListView)videoListViewContainer.findViewById(R.id.videoListView);
        VideoListAdapter adapter = new VideoListAdapter((LayoutInflater) mActivity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE));
        adapter.setList(videoObjects);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        DownloadThumbnailsTask task = new DownloadThumbnailsTask(videoObjects, adapter);
        task.execute();
    }
```

This is code of DownloadThumbnailsTask:

```
public class DownloadThumbnailsTask extends AsyncTask<List<VideoObject>, VideoObject, Void>{

        private List<VideoObject> videoObjectList = null;
        private List<VideoObject> toProcess = null;
        private VideoListAdapter adapter = null;

        public DownloadThumbnailsTask(List<VideoObject> videoObjectList, VideoListAdapter adapter){
            this.videoObjectList = videoObjectList;
            this.toProcess = new ArrayList<VideoObject>(videoObjectList);
            this.adapter = adapter;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(List<VideoObject>... lists) {

            for(int i=0; i<toProcess.size(); i++){
                VideoObject item = videoObjectList.get(i);
                String urldisplay = item.getThumbnailUrl();
                Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
                try {
                    InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                    mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                item.setThumbnail(mIcon11);
                mIcon11 = null;
                publishProgress(item);
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(VideoObject... values) {
            if(values != null && values.length > 0){
                VideoObject item = values[0];
                videoObjectList.remove(item);
                videoObjectList.add(item);
                adapter.setList(videoObjectList);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            this.toProcess.clear();
            this.toProcess = null;
        }
    }
```

This is code of adapter:

```
public class VideoListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private List<VideoObject> list;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public VideoListAdapter(LayoutInflater layoutInflater){
        this.layoutInflater = layoutInflater;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return list.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return list.get(i).getId();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        if(view == null){
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_video, viewGroup, false);
        }
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        view.setTag(viewHolder);
        VideoObject item = getVideoObjectItem(i);
        viewHolder.duration.setText(item.getFormattedDuration());
        viewHolder.title.setText(item.getName());
        if(item.getThumbnail() != null){
            viewHolder.thumbnail.setImageBitmap(item.getThumbnail());
        }
        return view;
    }

    private VideoObject getVideoObjectItem(int position){
        return (VideoObject) getItem(position);
    }

    public List<VideoObject> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(List<VideoObject> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        public final ImageView thumbnail;
        public final TextView title;
        public final TextView duration;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            this.thumbnail = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imgVideoThumbnail);
            this.title = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtVideoName);
            this.duration = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtVideoDuration);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is result of my code:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed two things:

1. Inside `doInBackground` you are waiting

   `InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
   mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);`

to complete before downloading the next image.

Try this:

```
    protected Void doInBackground(List<VideoObject>... lists) {
        for(final int i=0; i<toProcess.size(); i++){
            try {
                new Thread(){
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        VideoObject item = videoObjectList.get(i);
                        String urldisplay = item.getThumbnailUrl();
                        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
                        try {
                            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        item.setThumbnail(mIcon11);
                        publishProgress(item);
                    }
                }.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(VideoObject... values) {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

I think this two lines is the problem:

```
    videoObjectList.remove(item);
    videoObjectList.add(item);
```

You're removing an item and adding again at the bottom. Just call notifyDataSetChanged after setting the bitmap.

2. Inside `getView` you're creating a new ViewHolder every time.

   ```
   @Override
   public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
       ViewHolder viewHolder;
       if(view == null){
           view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_video, viewGroup, false);
           viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
           view.setTag(viewHolder);
       }else{
           viewHolder = view.getTag();
       }
       VideoObject item = getVideoObjectItem(i);
       viewHolder.duration.setText(item.getFormattedDuration());
       viewHolder.title.setText(item.getName());
       if(item.getThumbnail() != null){
           viewHolder.thumbnail.setImageBitmap(item.getThumbnail());
       }
       return view;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Do you get anything in your logcat? Maybe opening the stream or decoding fails. Are the images large?

Comment: No, i have no error in logcat, thanks. Gonji Dev's solution helpes me.